# Print HTML Files using Java without PRINT dialogue

Tags: java, html, printing, dialog

I am trying to print very simple HTML file using JAVA PrintServices API.

This is what I wrote for that -

```
public class WebTest {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String filename = "C:/tmp/PrintTest.html";
    PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    PrintService defaultService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    if (defaultService != null) {
        DocPrintJob job = defaultService.createPrintJob();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        DocAttributeSet das = new HashDocAttributeSet();
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, das);
        job.print(doc, pras);
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

However, my output file is not formatted properly - This is what I see in printed output -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <h2>Hello World.</h2>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to see Output as -

```
Hello World.
```

I also tried using Microsoft command for this - `"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office14\\msohtmed.exe\" /p  C:/tmp/PrintTest.html`

However its prompting me PRINT box which I want to get rid off.

My objective is just to get correctly printed output.

Please suggest suitable options.

I already referred other links, but couldn't find exact answer for what I am looking for.

Your help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML page should be rendered before printing (calculate margins, arrange text on the page, etc...). The simplest way to render and print html page is by using `JEditorPane` (in the following snippet without any additional formats, attributes and confirmation dialog):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws PrintException, IOException, PrinterException {
    JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
    editorPane.setEditable(false);
    URL urlToPage = new File("/home/me/Temp/page.html").toURI().toURL();
    editorPane.setPage(urlToPage);  
    editorPane.print(null, null, false, PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService(), null, false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes it worked for Simple HTML. Is it possible to extend this to slightly complex HTML, say HTML having some tables and cascaded style sheets. When I tried same code for HTML with CSS its giving me error - Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
 at javax.swing.text.CompositeView.getView(CompositeView.java:143)
 at javax.swing.text.View.forwardUpdate(View.java:1130)
 at javax.swing.text.BoxView.forwardUpdate(BoxView.java:223)
 at javax.swing.text.View.changedUpdate(View.java:767)

Comment: For complex HTML you need more sophisticated HTML rendering engine (like CSSBox)